# Improve and apply a better block code format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

HTML on page:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="New Message" name="New Message" id="subject">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Your Name: </label>
        <span class="your-name">
        <input type="text" id="name" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="email">E-Mail: </label>
        <input type="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="message">Tell Us Everything: </label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="button-con">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="return check_values();">
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

js file:

```
// JavaScript Document

var http = createRequestObject();
var areal = Math.random() + "";
var real = areal.substring(2,6);

function createRequestObject() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch(e) {
    try { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    catch(f) { xmlhttp=null; }
  }
  if(!xmlhttp&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!="undefined") {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    return  xmlhttp;
}

function sendRequest() {
    var rnd = Math.random();
    var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
    var email = escape(document.getElementById("email").value);
    var subject = escape(document.getElementById("subject").value);
    var message = escape(document.getElementById("message").value);

    try{
    http.open('POST',  'http://my-domain.com/form.php');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send('$name='+name+'&email='+email+'&subject='+subject+'&message='+message+'&rnd='+rnd);
    }
    catch(e){}
    finally{}
}

function check_values() {
    var valid = '';

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var body = document.getElementById("message").value;
    if(trim(name) == "" ||
        trim(email) == "" ||
        trim(subject) == "" ||
        trim(body) == "") {
            alert("Please complete all fields");
    } else {
        if(isEmail(email)) {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("submit").value='Please Wait..';
            sendRequest();
        } else {
            alert("Email appears to be invalid\nPlease check and try again");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            document.getElementById("email").select();
        }
    }
}

function handleResponse() {
    try{
    if((http.readyState == 4)&&(http.status == 200)){
        var response = http.responseText;
      document.getElementById("confirmation").innerHTML = response;
      document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display ="";
        }
  }
    catch(e){}
    finally{}
}

function isUndefined(a) {
   return typeof a == 'undefined';
}

function trim(a) {
    return a.replace(/^s*(S*(s+S+)*)s*$/, "$1");
}

function isEmail(a) {
   return (a.indexOf(".") > 0) && (a.indexOf("@") > 0);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
  $page_title = "Contact Us Form";
  $email_it_to = "test@test.com";
  $error_message = "Please complete the form first";
  $confirmation = "Thank you, your message has been successfully sent.";
?>


<?php
error_reporting(0);

include 'blah.com/form_config.php';

if(!isset($_POST['rnd']) || !isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    echo $error_message;
    die();
}
    $email_from = $email;
    $email_subject = "Contact Form: ".stripslashes($subject);
    $email_message = "Please find below a message submitted by '".stripslashes($name);
    $email_message .="' on ".date("d/m/Y")." at ".date("H:i")."\n\n";
    $email_message .= stripslashes($message);

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($email_it_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    echo "<b>$confirmation</b>";
    die();
?>
```

The code is getting all the way to changing the text on the submit button, but is not sending - any help is appreciated.

I can't seem to find the error - I added and removed a few things as trial and error, but can't seem to get it 100%

Comment: Are you receiving `$error_message` from your PHP script? At what point is it failing exactly?

Comment: creating a better code format for the HTML block code.

Comment: VTC as typo based on answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo: `http.send('$name=...`

You have `$` when you should have an ampersand `&`

Changing it to `http.send('&name=` in your javascript (within your `try{}` in the 
`sendRequest()` function) should then keep

```
if(!isset($_POST['rnd']) || !isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    echo $error_message;
    die();
}
```

from satisfying in your PHP, as `$_POST['name']` will actually *be* set, now that it's considered *part* of the querystring, and the rest of your mailer code will then execute.

Comment: Hey Marcus, I did as you suggested, but it is still freezing at the switch of the text on the button. It just says "Please Wait..." on the button and will not progress - no error message other than the generic one I made for the code if error reporting is on.

Comment: Which error is returning exactly? The $error_message one?

Comment: no message - just submit button changes to "Please Wait..." and stays there, no email sent

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the following line:

http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
     http.send('name='+name+'&email='+email+'&subject='+subject+'&message='+message+'&rnd='+rnd); 
//remove $ from the name as you are sending the value of name variable.
    }

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I just overlooked what the js was attempting to post to as Marcus suggested, here is the code needed:

```
$email_from = ($_POST['email']);
$email_subject = "Contact Form: ".($_POST['subject']);
$email_name = "Client Name: ".($_POST['name']);
$email_message = "From Email: ".($_POST['email']);
$email_message = "Their Message: ".($_POST['message']);
```

`mail($email_it_to, $email_subject, $email_name, $email_message, $headers);`

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for late respond, and if problem resolved thats good.

But a easy way to use ajax in my opinion is:

```js
$.ajax({
type:'post',
data:'&task=asdasd',
url:'ajax.php',
success:function(response){
alert(response);
}
})
```

Hope this will save time.